# zoomContainer not working on mobile or even in zoomed browser

Tags: mobile, opencart, responsive

Product images are opening like direct link to image on mobile devices, or even in zoomed in browser, they should be opening in zoomcontainer like on desktop.

Wierdest thing is that, when i open my page on desktop on normal 100% zoom and zoom in to 300-400-500% it works perfectly, BUT when i refresh page on these zoom leves (page reloads already zoomed in) its not working at all, and images are opening like direct links to images.

I have no idea what even can cause this so i dont know what code to paste here, never experienced anything like this before. 
Thank you for any help

You can check it here: https://winterland.sk/zimne-vychytavky/dotykove-rukavice

Answer (score 0):

You have an additional div on top of your image **id="#oknopredimg"**, so basically you click not image but that div. You can try to hide it.

```
@media (max-width: 1100px){
  #oknopredimg {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #f000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Same for other screens that you have **@media (max-width: 992px)...**